# Java GUI Accessing Buttons From showInputDialog

Tags: java, user-interface, button, dialog

Basically I have code that displays a dialog box and allows the user to choose between 2 and 4 players. It works fine however I want to be able to control what the 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons do but I can't figure out how to access them. When the 'OK' button is clicked I want to call a method and if cancel is clicked I will terminate the program (System.exit(0)). Also how do I check if the user clicks the 'x' in the top corner of the dialog box?

```
public void numPlayersDialog()
{
    Object[] possibilities = {"Two Players", "Three Players", "Four Players"};
    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    null,
                    "Enter the number of Players\n",
                    "Initial Dialog",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    possibilities,
                    "Two Players");


        if(s.equals("Two Players"))
        {
            setNumOfPlayers(2);
        }
        else if (s.equals("Three Players"))
        {
            setNumOfPlayers(3);
        }
        else
        {
            setNumOfPlayers(4);
        }
}
```

I'm fairly new to the GUI stuff in Java so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) says:

> Returns:
>
> user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

So, if the returned value is null, it means the user clicked Cancel or closed the dialog box. If the result isn't null, it means the user clicked OK.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, I read that entire page, however it still doesn't explain how I can control what happens when 'OK' is clicked.

Comment: when OK is clicked, the code after showInputDialog is executed. So you just need to check which value is returned and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Like that :

```
if (s == null) {/////////////mean you click on the Cancel button
        System.exit(0);
    } else {////////////mean you click on OK button

        if (s.equals("Two Players")) {
            setNumOfPlayers(2);
        } else if (s.equals("Three Players")) {
            setNumOfPlayers(3);
        } else {
            setNumOfPlayers(4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou, I feel slightly stupid that I didn't realise that now :/